# Django how to use webhook in django and send data to zapier?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, zapier

I am beginner in django. i read the docuemntation of rest api. how to send my model detail to zapier and how to make webhook and configuration?
kindly help me . how do i send my drivers  to zapier and connect with zapier when my driver book a car

**Models**

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = "booking"
        verbose_name = "Booking"
        verbose_name_plural = "Bookings"
        ordering = ['-booking_date']

    booking_car_car = models.ForeignKey(
        Car,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='booking_car_car_key'
    )
    booking_customer_customer = models.ForeignKey(
        Customer,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='booking_customer_customer'
    )
    booking_start_date = models.DateField(
        blank=False,
        null=False
    )
    booking_end_date = models.DateField(
        blank=False,
        null=False
    )
    booking_total_price = models.IntegerField(
        blank=False,
        null=False
    )
    booking_approved = models.NullBooleanField(
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    booking_date = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True,
        blank=False,
        null=False
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.booking_customer_customer.customer_firstname
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've no previous experience with Zapier but, You could do an `HTTP POST` request to zapier url by overriding model's `save()` method.

```
import requests

class SampleModel(models.Model):
    # your fields

    def save(self, *args,**kwargs):
        if not self.pk: #send webhook on "EVERY OBJECT CREATION"
            webhook_data = your data to be sent to zapier
            requests.post(url=zapier_url,
                         data=webhook_data)
```

Comment: Jerin my model is for booking car how do i utlize it . i didnt get

Comment: Show your models

Comment: Jerin i had edit my question with my models. how do i connect or use webhook .

Comment: Override the save method of your model, as in.my example

Comment: JPG webhook_data?  i didnt understand it . can you edit your question regarding to my model

Comment: As I said, I have no idea what the Zapier is and how it would accept the data. What I know is the ***logic*** to send some data to Zapier over HTTP.

Comment: so i just need to send data using this model save?

Comment: You can send whatever data to Zapier, whenever you want ( I assume that,). If you want to send the data ***only the time of a NEW booking***, you could use **signal** feature of Django, or you could override the `save()` method

Comment: Yeah.. That is what I meant

Comment: Thankyou JPG . ill make it if ill get some problem ill in touch with you .